# How to concatenate 2 datasets whilst removing superfluous columns in R Studio?

Tags: r, csv

I have 2 CSV datasets:

**File 1:**

```
Identity,Number,Data,Result,RT
5,3,13,45,34
6,1,44,12,56
3,1,67,23,47
0,6,43,55,91
4,5,33,34,29
```

**File 2:**

```
Identity,NB,NB,Result,Data,
1,4,55,92,62
3,7,43,12,74
7,3,58,52,64
0,6,10,22,96
3,8,13,92,22
```

I would like to concatenate these two datasets to create one dataset with the data of file 2 beneath the data of file 1 in the correct corresponding columns.

**File 3:**

```
Identity,Number,Data,Result,RT
5,3,13,45,34
6,1,44,12,56
3,1,67,23,47
0,6,43,55,91
4,5,33,34,29

Identity,NB,NB,Result,Data,
1,4,55,92,62
3,7,43,12,74
7,3,58,52,64
0,6,10,22,96
3,8,13,92,22
```

But where the columns for Data and Result line up on top of one another.

N.B.The columns with the corresponding data in file 1 don't align with the columns holding the same data in file 2.

Comment: You can do something like this but R IS NOT Excel, so the format you ask for will not be possible to achieve with R dataframes or matrices. You could of course use R to build a CSV file that looked like that.  .... but why would you?

Comment: Do you really want to repeat the headers like that?

Comment: @Elin, no - I just wanted to illustrate that the columns don't align (but that I want them to).

Comment: I'm sorry ... do you want the values to line up under the correct column names and to end up with the list of unique column names across the top?

Comment: Also is identity unique? For example you have 0 in both tables, is that the same unit or different?

Comment: do you want the values to line up under the correct column names and to end up with the list of unique column names across the top? Yes. And the 0 is the same unit - they are not unique identities. The example from Darren seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your expected output is an object in R, it's impossible. If you mean that File 3 is a csv file binding File 1 and 2, then you can try this :

```
f1 <- read.csv("file1.csv")
f2 <- read.csv("file2.csv")

inter <- intersect(names(f1), names(f2))
diff1 <- names(f1)[! names(f1) %in% inter]
diff2 <- names(f2)[! names(f2) %in% inter]

write.table(f1[c(inter, diff1)], "file3.csv", quote = F, sep = ",", row.names = F)
write.table(f2[c(inter, diff2)], "file3.csv", quote = F, sep = ",", row.names = F, append = T)

# append = T is applicable to write.table, not write.csv.
```

**file3.csv**

```
Identity,Data,Result,Number,RT
5,13,45,3,34
6,44,12,1,56
3,67,23,1,47
0,43,55,6,91
4,33,34,5,29
Identity,Data,Result,NB,NB.1
1,62,92,4,55
3,74,12,7,43
7,64,52,3,58
0,96,22,6,10
3,22,92,8,13
```

Use Excel to open it:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible so that C column has 'Data' from file 1 (column c) and 'Data' from file 2 (column E), both in the same column, or does this need to be moved manually?

Comment: Do you mean to move the 3 columns which have the same names together and align them? See the edit.

Comment: That is exactly what I was after, just with removing row 7. Thank you. But the data I provided was just an example. I need to use the same principles for two much larger datasets. I'm trying to work out from the code, how I can extrapolate this technique for 2 datasets which are both at least 20 columns wide?

Comment: Of course, you can use my code above to solve it without revising anything.

Comment: On the condition that you need to read both CSV files into R successfully.